# Status code 300 return error in catch block when using axios

Tags: javascript, http, axios

When i am making a http call with axios it goes in catch block with error
My requirement is to handle the 300 response in then block it should not got to catch, how can i achieve that through axios

Comment: Please go through [300 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/300) and please show us what you have done.

Comment: If you need to handle error globally, Use axios interceptor https://medium.com/@danielalvidrez/handling-error-responses-with-grace-b6fd3c5886f0

Comment: @MebinJoe I think using interceptors wont help me because i want it to stop going into catch block for status code 300 rather than transforming request or response objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have multiple choices. You can either extract your code from `then` callback into function - and call it in error handler when status code is 300.

You could also try this option from axios, to reject the promise only when the status code is > 301.

```
axios.get('/user/12345', {
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status <= 300; // Reject only if the status code is greater than 300
  }
})
```

Comment: I saw this in documentation but i want only for status code 300 for other status codes i wnat it to be default

Comment: Sure, you can just "whitelist" code 300. Try condition - status <= 300. This would complete your promise for all 200 codes and code 300.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what do you mean by white-listing it, it will be helpful if you can elaborate the steps

Answer (score 0):

I've needed something a bit more dynamic:

```js
// oversimplified index.js

const axios = require('axios')

const allowedStatusList = json.parse(process.env.ALLOWED_STATUSES) || ["2xx"]
// ^^ check that it's a valid input yourself :p 

const validateRequestStatusCode = allowedStatuses => {
  const stringStatuses = allowedStatuses.map(String)
  return status => {
    if (stringStatuses.includes(String(status))) {
      return true
    } else {
      for (let wildCardStatus of stringStatuses) {
        const validRange = wildCardStatus.match(/.+?(?=xx)/g)
        if (validRange && String(status).substring(0, 1) == validRange[0]) {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
    return false
  }
}

const axiosConfig = {
  validateStatus: validateRequestStatusCode(allowedStatusList),
  url,
  data
  // etc
}

axios(axiosConfig)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

This would allow you to just supply an environment variable (or however you want to do your config) to change what statuses are valid.

For example, setting `ALLOWED_STATUSES='["2xx", "3xx", "4xx"]'` would allow any status code from 200 and 499.
Set `ALLOWED_STATUSES='[200, 201, "3xx"]'` and you'd have a far more specific filter.